# Trying to set an interval for a carrousel in OOP, using methods

Tags: javascript, methods, carousel

For a school project i'm coding a slideshow and the javascript part should use object oriented programming - I've a method "nextSlide" that switch between image to animate the carrousel and I want the animation to perform automatically every 5 seconds :

I've tried the following code but it doesn't seems to work,

```
var diaporama = {
  slides : document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide'),
  currentSlide : 0,

  nextSlide : function() {
      slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
      currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
      slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
  },
  slideInterval : function() {
    setInterval(this.nextSlide(), 5000)
  }
}

diaporama.slideInterval();
```

The animation doesn't perform and Firefox give me the following error : SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'
SyntaxError: missing formal parameter

Edit : I found a way to make it work by tweeking my code like this:

```
  nextSlide : function() {
      this.slides[this.currentSlide].className = 'slide';
      this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide+1)%this.slides.length;
      this.slides[this.currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
  }

}

var myVar = setInterval("diaporama.nextSlide()", 5000)
```

Comment: Hint: Read [this about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#The_this_problem)

Comment: Thank you I think it fit the context - but I have a hard time understanding the example presented in the link you provided. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how the code is for a OOP school project, I think you could use better OOP way to write your code:

```
    class Diaporama {
        constructor(containerSelector, itemSelector, interval) {

            var _containerSelector = containerSelector;
            var _itemSelector = itemSelector;
            var _interval = interval;

            var _slides = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            var _currentSlide = 0;

            setSlideInterval();
        }

        get slides() {
            return this._slides;
        }

        set slides(value) {
            this._slides = value;
        }

        get currentSlide() {
            return this._currentSlide;
        }

        set currentSlide(value) {
            this._slid_currentSlidees = value;
        }

        get containerSelector() {
            return this._containerSelector;
        }

        get itemSelector() {
            return this._itemSelector;
        }

        get interval() {
            return this._interval;
        }

        nextSlide() {
            slides[currentSlide].className = this.itemSelector;
            currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
            slides[currentSlide].className = this.itemSelector + ' showing';
        }

        setSlideInterval() {
            setInterval(this.nextSlide(), this.interval);
        }
    }
    //instance
    var mySlide = new Diaporama('#slides', '.slide', 5000);
```

Here is are reference to javascript classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

The `get` syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

The `set` syntax binds an object property to a function to be called when there is an attempt to set that property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Comment: This is indeed a very good idea, thanks for providing me with this !

Comment: I did vote up ! Altough my vote is not visble since my account is new. :) There's part of the code you posted that I don't fully understand : all theses set and get, can you explain this part ? Thanks !

Comment: In javascript classes the get/set enable you to access the method/function like a member with no `()`, like this `obj.interval = 5000;` to set values. Or just to get values like `console.log(obj.interval);` . If you feel this answer all your question you may mark as a answer (not need to vote up)

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful !

Answer (score 0):

It work if I add this reference to the nextSlide function :

```
  nextSlide : function() {
      this.slides[this.currentSlide].className = 'slide';
      this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide+1)%this.slides.length;
      this.slides[this.currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
  }

}

var myVar = setInterval("diaporama.nextSlide()", 5000)
```